# Can I make a game using c++ that will run on the web?

Tags: c++, directx

There is some libraries that lets you run C++.  So, it is it possible to run a game that uses directx full mode screen?

Answer (score 2):

Google is developing a tool to allow this kind of thing via Chrome. It is called Chrome Native Client, or NACL for short.  http://blog.chromium.org/2010/05/sneak-peek-at-native-client-sdk.html

Comment: Nice to know that something is available in C/C++ also. Thanks Jim.

Answer (score 1):

In general, no. Most online games are written with Javascript, Flash, the newly hatchedd HTML5 and similar technologies. Perhaps C++ integration is possible on some level, but you definitely cannot write a browser-hosted game purely and entirely in C++.

Answer (score 1):

it could also be done with an ActiveX control.  ActiveX only works in IE. there are Netscape plugins that work in other browsers.  so make a solution that contains both.  you need a book on ActiveX/COM/OLE.  Better yet, take a class if you can find one, you will learn far more, because COM is not an easy subject to just read about and then really do - versioning is a big problem.

nope, not supported in firefox. but read this: http://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/webmasters-faq.html#activex

some people may have activex controls disabled.  if this is the case, your game will not run.  you will have to tell the user that they will need to change their security settings in IE.  you can get feedback from the object element in javascript as to whether or not the activex loaded.  there is code out there for that.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sw4ddf8%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
examples are all over the internet.